# Getting all text between dates

Tags: php, regex

I have a dilemma as of the moment on how can I separate below line, into two different variables:

```
03/07/12 12:19:41 (JOHN.DOE.9): Hi, Kindly proceed with the construnction 02/02/12 06:52:54 (JANE.DOE.2): Hi Sir, this is to ask for your approval in the pending construction.
```

!!!Please do note that this is a one-liner string

**Desired output are the following:**

```
$string1 = '03/07/12 12:19:41 (JOHN.DOE.9) : Hi, Kindly proceed with the construction.'
$string2 = '02/02/12 06:52:54 (JANE.DOE.2): Hi Sir, this is to ask for your approval in the pending construction.'
```

Current Result with my code:

> 03/07/12 12:19:41 (JOHN.DOE.9) : Hi, Kindly proceed with the construction **02/02/12**

We can see here that I'm also getting the preceding date that should be included in the next variable(Jane Doe's)

Code that I'm using:

```
$txt='03/07/12 12:19:41 (JOHN.DOE.9): Hi, Kindly proceed with the construnction 02/02/12 06:52:54 (JANE.DOE.2): Hi Sir, this is to ask for your approval in the pending construction.';

$re1='((?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\\/.](?:(?:\\d{1}\\d{1})))(?![\\d])';    # MMDDYY 1
$re2='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
$re3='((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)';  # HourMinuteSec 1
$re4='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
$re5='(\\(.*\\))';  # Round Braces 1
$re6='(:)'; # Any Single Character 1
$re7='( )'; # White Space 1   $re8='((?:[a-z][a-z].+?)((?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\\/.](?:(?:\\d{1}\\d{1}))))';    # Word 1

if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5.$re6.$re7.$re8."/is", $txt, $matches))   {
      $mmddyy1=$matches[1][0];
      $time1=$matches[2][0];
      $rbraces1=$matches[3][0];
      $c1=$matches[4][0];
      $ws1=$matches[5][0];
      $word1=$matches[6][0];
      print "$mmddyy1 $time1 $rbraces1 $c1 $ws1 $word1 \n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead to find the following date without including it in the match. Something like this should work:

```
$re = '~(?<date> \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2} \s+ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} ) .*? (?= (?&date) | $)~x';
preg_match_all($re, $txt, $matches);
```

Or you could split on the date in a lookahead, and exclude the first empty element.

```
$array = preg_split('~(?= \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2} \s+ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )~x', $txt, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Hi Qtax,

Tried your first suggested REGEX and it worked. Would you mind to explain why it was constructed like that?

Answer (score 1):

What's a complicate regex!

```
$regex = '/(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)(.*)(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)(.*)/';
```

This simple regex should help you.

Comment: Tried the above regex but dates weren't successfully captured:

Result:
06:52:54 (JANE.DOE.2): Hi Sir, this is to ask for your approval in the pending construction.
12:19:41 (JOHN.DOE.9): Hi, Kindly proceed with the construnction

Comment: @Kevin, The string has been split. All you need to do is to construct the $matches yourself.